# Remove all constraints affecting a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, constraints, autolayout

I have a UIView which is placed on the screen via several constraints. Some of the constraints are owned by the superview, others are owned by other ancestors (e.g. perhaps the view property of a UIViewController).

I want to remove all of these old constraints, and place it somewhere new using new constraints.

How can I do this without creating an IBOutlet for every single constraint and having to remember which view owns said constraint?

To elaborate, the naive approach would be to create a bunch of IBOutlets for each of the constraints, and would then involve calling code such as:

```
[viewA removeConstraint:self.myViewsLeftConstraint];
[viewB removeConstraint:self.myViewsTopConstraint];
[viewB removeConstraint:self.myViewsBottomConstraint];
[self.view removeConstraint:self.myViewsRightConstraint];
```

The problem with this code is that even in the simplest case, I would need to create 2 IBOutlets. For complex layouts, this could easily reach 4 or 8 required IBOutlets. Furthermore, I would need to ensure that my call to remove the constraint is being called on the proper view. For example, imagine that `myViewsLeftConstraint` is owned by `viewA`. If I were to accidentally call `[self.view removeConstraint:self.myViewsLeftConstraint]`, nothing would happen.

**Note:** The method [constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:) looks promising, but is intended for debugging purposes only.

---

**Update:** Many of the answers I am receiving deal with `self.constraints`, `self.superview.constraints`, or some variant of those. These solutions won't work since those methods return only the constraints *owned* by the view, not the ones *affecting* the view.

To clarify the problem with these solutions, consider this view hierarchy:

- Grandfather

  - Father

    - Me

      - Son
      - Daughter
    - Brother
  - Uncle

Now imagine we create the following constraints, and always attach them to their nearest common ancestor:

- C0: Me: same top as Son (owned by Me)
- C1: Me: width = 100 (owned by Me)
- C2: Me: same height as Brother (owned by Father)
- C3: Me: same top as Uncle (owned by Grandfather)
- C4: Me: same left as Grandfather (owned by Grandfather)
- C5: Brother: same left as Father (owned by Father)
- C6: Uncle: same left as Grandfather (owned by Grandfather)
- C7: Son: same left as Daughter (owned by Me)

Now imagine we want to remove all constraints affecting `Me`. Any proper solution should remove `[C0,C1,C2,C3,C4]` and nothing else.

If I use `self.constraints` (where self is Me), I will get `[C0,C1,C7]`, since those are the only constraints owned by Me. Obviously it wouldn't be enough to remove this since it is missing `[C2,C3,C4]`. Furthermore, it is removing `C7` unnecessarily.

If I use `self.superview.constraints` (where self is Me), I will get `[C2,C5]`, since those are the constraints owned by Father. Obviously we cannot remove all these since `C5` is completely unrelated to `Me`.

If I use `grandfather.constraints`, I will get `[C3,C4,C6]`. Again, we cannot remove all of these since `C6` should remain intact.

The brute force approach is to loop over each of the view's ancestors (including itself), and seeing if `firstItem` or `secondItem` are the view itself; if so, remove that constraint. This will lead to a correct solution, returning `[C0,C1,C2,C3,C4]`, and only those constraints.

However, I'm hoping there is a more elegant solution than having to loop through the entire list of ancestors.

Comment: How about you put an identifier to all the constraints you want to remove ? This way you do not need to keep an outlet for them.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The only solution I have found so far is to remove the view from its superview:

```
[view removeFromSuperview]
```

This looks like it removes all constraints affecting its layout and is ready to be added to a superview and have new constraints attached. However, it will incorrectly remove any subviews from the hierarchy as well, and get rid of `[C7]` incorrectly.

Comment: You could use the firstItem and secondItem properties of the constraints to check if they apply to your view and loop through the view hierarchy to find all of them. I think removing and re-adding is a better solution, though. I'd be interested to see your use case since it seems like this is a very bad thing to be doing. Your constraints could easily become completely invalid since other views may be relying on those constraints to lay out properly.

Comment: @bjtitus: Good point. However, in this specific case, I am repositioning a view which has nothing dependent on it. It uses other views in order to know where to be placed, and there are no views that use it in order to know where to be placed.

Comment: Not the only solution, but very simple. In my use case I have just removed the view from superview and then re-added it later.

Answer (score 85):

This approach worked for me:

```
@interface UIView (RemoveConstraints)

- (void)removeAllConstraints;

@end


@implementation UIView (RemoveConstraints)

- (void)removeAllConstraints
{
    UIView *superview = self.superview;
    while (superview != nil) {
        for (NSLayoutConstraint *c in superview.constraints) {
            if (c.firstItem == self || c.secondItem == self) {
                [superview removeConstraint:c];
            }
        }
        superview = superview.superview;
    }

    [self removeConstraints:self.constraints];
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
}

@end
```

After it's done executing your view remains where it was because it creates autoresizing constraints.  When I don't do this the view usually disappears.  Additionally, it doesn't just remove constraints from superview but traversing all the way up as there may be constraints affecting it in ancestor views.

#### Swift 4 Version

```
extension UIView {
    
    public func removeAllConstraints() {
        var _superview = self.superview
        
        while let superview = _superview {
            for constraint in superview.constraints {
                
                if let first = constraint.firstItem as? UIView, first == self {
                    superview.removeConstraint(constraint)
                }
                
                if let second = constraint.secondItem as? UIView, second == self {
                    superview.removeConstraint(constraint)
                }
            }
            
            _superview = superview.superview
        }
        
        self.removeConstraints(self.constraints)
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the official answer.

Comment: why do you have 
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
? you literally never want this for views you are setting up with constraints?

Comment: I'm removing the constraints, so I want to use the autoresize constraints after I remove the other constraints to hold it in place, without that line in my code the view would disappear

Comment: I needed to *log* all constraints on a view for debugging purposes and I was able to modify this answer slightly to do that. +1

Comment: This would incorrectly remove `C7`. However, it should be easy to fix if you remove `[self removeConstraints:self.constraints];` and change `UIView *superview = self.superview;` to `UIView *superview = self;`.

Comment: Why you did -     self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;? That's completely blow up my console log with errors until i removed it. You need to set it to false if you work with constraints in code.

Comment: In my case if I set self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false afterwards and add new constraints it works.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic. Thank you, almost 8 years later.

Answer (score 59):

You can remove all constraints in a view by doing this:

```
self.removeConstraints(self.constraints)
```

EDIT: To remove the constraints of all subviews, use the following extension in Swift:

```
extension UIView {
    func clearConstraints() {
        for subview in self.subviews {
            subview.clearConstraints()
        }
        self.removeConstraints(self.constraints)
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it removes only the constraints that this view owns (e.g. its width and height). It does not remove things such as the leading and top constraints.

Comment: I haven't verified your comment above. However, I believe this would work the same as or better than above,
    [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:self.constraints];

Comment: That would suffer from the same problem as the original solution. `self.constraints` only returns the constraints that `self` owns, not all the constraints that affect `self`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying now. In my *answer*, I am removing the constraints from the UITableViewCell's contentView. The method updateConstraints would then add constraints for all subviews and reset the layout. In my first *comment* above, I should have typed self.view.constraints. Both self.view and self.contentView are at the top of the view hierarchy. Setting translatesAutoresizingMasksToConstraints = YES on self.view or self.contentView is a bad idea. ;-). 
I don't like calls to addSubview: in my updateConstraints method, removing the view from the hierarchy seems unnecessary imo.

Comment: I just updated the question to show why a solution like this won't work for what I'm looking to do. Assuming you are within a UITableViewCell the equivalent of contentView is Grandfather. Therefore your solution would incorrectly remove `[C6]`, and incorrectly not remove `[C0,C1,C2]`.

Comment: In my case, it no remove any constraints.

Comment: this is totally wrong, as explained by @Senseful

Answer (score 26):

There are two ways of on how to achieve that according to **Apple Developer Documentation**

#### 1. `NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints`

> This is a convenience method that provides an easy way to deactivate a
>   set of constraints with one call. The effect of this method is the
>   same as setting the isActive property of each constraint to false.
>   Typically, using this method is more efficient than deactivating each
>   constraint individually.

```
// Declaration
class func deactivate(_ constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint])

// Usage
NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(yourView.constraints)
```

#### 2. `UIView.removeConstraints` (Deprecated for >= iOS 8.0)

> When developing for iOS 8.0 or later, use the NSLayoutConstraint
>   class’s deactivateConstraints: method instead of calling the
>   removeConstraints: method directly. The deactivateConstraints: method
>   automatically removes the constraints from the correct views.

```
// Declaration
func removeConstraints(_ constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint])`

// Usage
yourView.removeConstraints(yourView.constraints)
```

### Tips

Using `Storyboard`s or `XIB`s can be such a pain at configuring the constraints as mentioned on your scenario, you have to create IBOutlets for each ones you want to remove. Even so, most of the time `Interface Builder` creates more trouble than it solves.

Therefore when having very dynamic content and different states of the view, I would suggest:

1. Creating your views programmatically
2. Layout them and using [NSLayoutAnchor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutanchor)
3. Append each constraint that might get removed later to an array
4. Clear them every time before applying the new state

**Simple Code**

```
private var customConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

private func activate(constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]) {
    customConstraints.append(contentsOf: constraints)
    customConstraints.forEach { $0.isActive = true }
}

private func clearConstraints() {
    customConstraints.forEach { $0.isActive = false }
    customConstraints.removeAll()
}

private func updateViewState() {
    clearConstraints()

    let constraints = [
        view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.leadingAnchor),
        view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.trailingAnchor),
        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.topAnchor),
        view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.bottomAnchor)
    ]

    activate(constraints: constraints)

    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

### References

1. [NSLayoutConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526066-deactivate?changes=latest_minor)
2. [UIView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622593-removeconstraints)

Comment: Be careful. Views that specify an intrinsic content size will have NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint added automatically by iOS. Removing this by accessing the normal yourView.constraints property will break autolayout on those views.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it removes only the constraints that this view owns (e.g. its width and height). It does not remove things such as the leading and top constraints.

Comment: Yeah, what Senseful said. Although these methods do exist, they do not on their own solve the problem the question is actually asking about.

Answer (score 19):

In Swift:

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {

    /**
     Removes all constrains for this view
     */
    func removeConstraints() {

        let constraints = self.superview?.constraints.filter{
            $0.firstItem as? UIView == self || $0.secondItem as? UIView == self
        } ?? []

        self.superview?.removeConstraints(constraints)
        self.removeConstraints(self.constraints)
    }
}
```

Comment: This will crash if your view has no superview in 'superview!'. Please wrap the part into an 'if let superview = superview' :)

Comment: This will not remove all constraints. Constraints take the nearest parent of the 2 affected views, so if you make a constraint that does not share the superview of this view, that constraint will not be removed...

Comment: perhaps more correct would be to compare identity `if c.firstItem === self` instead of casting `as? UIView` and check equality with `==`

Comment: Should probably not use removeConstraints: from apple doc: // The removeConstraints method will be deprecated in a future release and should be avoided.  Instead use +[NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:].

Comment: @eonist the answer is 3 years ago. Instead of criticism you should edit it.

Comment: @Alexander Volkov True that. Just didn't have time ;)

Answer (score 6):

### Details

- Xcode 10.2.1 (10E1001), Swift 5

### Solution

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {

    func removeConstraints() { removeConstraints(constraints) }
    func deactivateAllConstraints() { NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(getAllConstraints()) }
    func getAllSubviews() -> [UIView] { return UIView.getAllSubviews(view: self) }

    func getAllConstraints() -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {
        var subviewsConstraints = getAllSubviews().flatMap { $0.constraints }
        if let superview = self.superview {
            subviewsConstraints += superview.constraints.compactMap { (constraint) -> NSLayoutConstraint? in
                if let view = constraint.firstItem as? UIView, view == self { return constraint }
                return nil
            }
        }
        return subviewsConstraints + constraints
    }

    class func getAllSubviews(view: UIView) -> [UIView] {
        return view.subviews.flatMap { [$0] + getAllSubviews(view: $0) }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
print("constraints: \(view.getAllConstraints().count), subviews: \(view.getAllSubviews().count)")
view.deactivateAllConstraints()
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift**

Following UIView Extension will remove all Edge constraints of a view:

```
extension UIView {
    func removeAllConstraints() {
        if let _superview = self.superview {
            self.removeFromSuperview()
            _superview.addSubview(self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually working nicely.

Answer (score 3):

The easier and efficient approach is to remove the view from superView and re add as subview again.
this causes all the subview constraints get removed automagically.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following method to remove all constraints from a view:

.h file:

```
+ (void)RemoveContraintsFromView:(UIView*)view 
    removeParentConstraints:(bool)parent 
    removeChildConstraints:(bool)child;
```

.m file:

```
+ (void)RemoveContraintsFromView:(UIView *)view 
    removeParentConstraints:(bool)parent 
    removeChildConstraints:(bool)child
{
    if (parent) {
        // Remove constraints between view and its parent.
        UIView *superview = view.superview;
        [view removeFromSuperview];
        [superview addSubview:view];
    }

    if (child) {
        // Remove constraints between view and its children.
        [view removeConstraints:[view constraints]];
    }
}
```

You can also [read this post](http://www.ryadel.com/2015/03/26/objective-c-removing-storyboard-constraints-programmatically/) on my blog to better understand how it works behind the hood.

If you need more granular control, I'd **strongly** advise switching to [Masonry](https://github.com/Masonry/Masonry), a powerful framework class you could use whenever you need to properly handle constraints programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

A Swift solution:

```
extension UIView {
  func removeAllConstraints() {
    var view: UIView? = self
    while let currentView = view {
      currentView.removeConstraints(currentView.constraints.filter {
        return $0.firstItem as? UIView == self || $0.secondItem as? UIView == self
      })
      view = view?.superview
    }
  }
}
```

It's important to go through all the parents, since the constraints between two elements are holds by the common ancestors, so just clearing the superview as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30379385/2054629) is not good enough, and you might end up having bad surprise later on.

Answer (score 2):

#### Based on previous answers (swift 4)

You can use immediateConstraints when you don't want to crawl entire hierarchies.

```
extension UIView {
/**
 * Deactivates immediate constraints that target this view (self + superview)
 */
func deactivateImmediateConstraints(){
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.immediateConstraints)
}
/**
 * Deactivates all constrains that target this view
 */
func deactiveAllConstraints(){
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.allConstraints)
}
/**
 * Gets self.constraints + superview?.constraints for this particular view
 */
var immediateConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint]{
    let constraints = self.superview?.constraints.filter{
        $0.firstItem as? UIView === self || $0.secondItem as? UIView === self
        } ?? []
    return self.constraints + constraints
}
/**
 * Crawls up superview hierarchy and gets all constraints that affect this view
 */
var allConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint] {
    var view: UIView? = self
    var constraints:[NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    while let currentView = view {
        constraints += currentView.constraints.filter {
            return $0.firstItem as? UIView === self || $0.secondItem as? UIView === self
        }
        view = view?.superview
    }
    return constraints
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With objectiveC

```
[self.superview.constraints enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(__kindof NSLayoutConstraint * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = (NSLayoutConstraint *)obj;
        if (constraint.firstItem == self || constraint.secondItem == self) {
            [self.superview removeConstraint:constraint];
        }
    }];
    [self removeConstraints:self.constraints];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using a Reusable Sequence

I decided to approach this in a more 'reusable' way.  Since finding all constraints affecting a view is the basis for all of the above, I decided to implement a custom sequence that returns them all for me, along with the owning views.

First thing to do is define an extension on `Arrays` of `NSLayoutConstraint` that returns all elements affecting a specific view.

```
public extension Array where Element == NSLayoutConstraint {

    func affectingView(_ targetView:UIView) -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {

        return self.filter{

            if let firstView = $0.firstItem as? UIView,
                firstView == targetView {
                return true
            }

            if let secondView = $0.secondItem as? UIView,
                secondView == targetView {
                return true
            }

            return false
        }
    }
}
```

We then use that extension in a custom sequence that returns all constraints affecting that view, along with the views that actually own them (which can be anywhere up the view hierarchy)

```
public struct AllConstraintsSequence : Sequence {

    public init(view:UIView){
        self.view = view
    }

    public let view:UIView

    public func makeIterator() -> Iterator {
        return Iterator(view:view)
    }

    public struct Iterator : IteratorProtocol {

        public typealias Element = (constraint:NSLayoutConstraint, owningView:UIView)

        init(view:UIView){
            targetView  = view
            currentView = view
            currentViewConstraintsAffectingTargetView = currentView.constraints.affectingView(targetView)
        }

        private let targetView  : UIView
        private var currentView : UIView
        private var currentViewConstraintsAffectingTargetView:[NSLayoutConstraint] = []
        private var nextConstraintIndex = 0

        mutating public func next() -> Element? {

            while(true){

                if nextConstraintIndex < currentViewConstraintsAffectingTargetView.count {
                    defer{nextConstraintIndex += 1}
                    return (currentViewConstraintsAffectingTargetView[nextConstraintIndex], currentView)
                }

                nextConstraintIndex = 0

                guard let superview = currentView.superview else { return nil }

                self.currentView = superview
                self.currentViewConstraintsAffectingTargetView = currentView.constraints.affectingView(targetView)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally we declare an extension on `UIView` to expose all the constraints affecting it in a simple property that you can access with a simple for-each syntax.

```
extension UIView {

    var constraintsAffectingView:AllConstraintsSequence {
        return AllConstraintsSequence(view:self)
    }
}
```

Now we can iterate all constraints affecting a view and do what we want with them...

List their identifiers...

```
for (constraint, _) in someView.constraintsAffectingView{
    print(constraint.identifier ?? "No identifier")
}
```

Deactivate them...

```
for (constraint, _) in someView.constraintsAffectingView{
    constraint.isActive = false
}
```

Or remove them entirely...

```
for (constraint, owningView) in someView.constraintsAffectingView{
    owningView.removeConstraints([constraint])
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
[viewA.superview.constraints enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = (NSLayoutConstraint *)obj;
    if (constraint.firstItem == viewA || constraint.secondItem == viewA) {
        [viewA.superview removeConstraint:constraint];
    }
}];

[viewA removeConstraints:viewA.constraints];
```

Basically, this is enumerates over all the constraints on the superview of viewA and removes all of the constraints that are related to viewA.

Then, the second part removes the constraints from viewA using the array of viewA's constraints.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it removes only the constraints that are owned by the superview. It does not remove all constraints affecting the view. (E.g. you could have just as easily set up constraints on the superview's superview's superview, which wouldn't be removed using this solution.)

Comment: I just updated the question to show why this solution will not work. This is the closest to being correct, since it's closest to the brute force solution I mention above. However, this solution will incorrectly remove `[C7]` and will incorrectly not remove `[C3,C4]`.

Comment: you could design the method to crawl up the hierarchy. But this solution is good enough, since you should add constraints above immediate superview anyway. IMO

Answer (score 0):

*(As of July 31, 2017)*

**SWIFT 3**

```
self.yourCustomView.removeFromSuperview()
self.yourCustomViewParentView.addSubview(self.yourCustomView)
```

**Objective C**

```
[self.yourCustomView removeFromSuperview];
[self.yourCustomViewParentView addSubview:self.yourCustomView];
```

This is the easiest way to quickly remove all constraints that exist on a UIView. Just be sure to add the UIView back with it's new constraints or new frame afterwards =)

Answer (score -1):

This is the way to disable all constraints from a specific view

```
 NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(myView.constraints)
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it removes only the constraints that this view owns (e.g. its width and height). It does not remove things such as the leading and top constraints.