# clear constraints when using NSLayoutAnchor

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I'm new in creating views without interface builder .
I'm using `NSLayoutAnchors` to create views!

when I'm using some view that created in viewcontroller like this :

```
let borderView:UIView = {

    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    view.alpha = 0.5
    return view

}()
```

then i use this view to border sth in view like this :

```
view.addSubview(borderView)
borderView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
borderView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
borderView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
borderView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true
```

then in another view i try this :

```
    informationView.addSubview(borderView)

    borderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: informationView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    borderView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: informationView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    borderView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: informationView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    borderView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true
```

but looks like this view has it's previous constraints end show constraints error !

how can I remove `borderView` constraints before reusing it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all constraints affecting a UIView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418884/remove-all-constraints-affecting-a-uiview)

Comment: It's not really a duplicate because the answer is not to reuse the view (removing constraints wouldn't help in this case)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't reuse views.  Each view can only be in the view hierarchy one time. You need to make a new bordered view object for each view you want to use it with.

To answer the question, you can remove constraints from a view with `view.removeConstraints(view.constraints)`

Comment: what is a best practice to make some border view using this method ?

Comment: Something like: (1) don't have a property for it (2) make a func that takes a view, makes a new border view, sets constraints and adds it as a sub to the passed in view, so you just do `addBorderView(to: view)`