# How do you remove constraint centerXAnchor?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit, nslayoutconstraint

I have a button placed in the center using centerXAnchor of superview, but now I have to change the position of the button from centerX to align leading from code. However, it's not moving to the left. Instead, it gets full width button.

```swift
buttonView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

buttonView!.removeConstraints(buttonView!.constraints)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    buttonView!.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.leadingAnchor, constant: 12),
    buttonView!.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
])
```

Comment: Are you setting up your initial constraints in Storyboard or via code? Are you also **changing** the bottom constraint?

Comment: yes i am setting up my initial constraints in Storyboard and changing bottom constraints is optional

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to do this, depending on exactly what you need to accomplish.

First, you said you're laying out your views in Storyboard, so...

If we're talking about one (or a few) specific views, we can create `@IBOutlet` vars for the constraints you want to change.

In Storyboard:

- give your buttonView a centerX constraint, with `Priority: Required (1000)`
- give your buttonView your desired leading constraint, with `Priority: Low (250)`

Connect them to outlets:

```
@IBOutlet var buttonCenterConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var buttonLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then, to switch from centered to leading:

```
buttonCenterConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
buttonLeadingConstraint.priority = .required
```

and you can "toggle" it back to centered with:

```
buttonLeadingConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
buttonCenterConstraint.priority = .required
```

Perhaps do the same thing with centerY and bottom constraints.

If you want a little more "flexibility," you could do something like this:

- in Storyboard, set only the centerX constraint

Then, to change that to a leading constraint:

```
// find the centerX constraint and de-activate it
if let cxConstraint = mainView.constraints.first(where: { ($0.firstAttribute == .centerX && $0.firstItem === buttonView) }) {
    cxConstraint.isActive = false
} else if let cxConstraint = mainView.constraints.first(where: { ($0.firstAttribute == .centerX && $0.secondItem === buttonView) }) {
    cxConstraint.isActive = false
}
// add a new leading constraint
buttonView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainView.leadingAnchor, constant: 12.0).isActive = true
```

You *could* also use an extension as suggested by someone else to "remove all constraints" ... but you risk removing constraints that you ***do not*** want changed.

Answer (score 0):

first remove all Constraint

```
extension UIView {

public func removeAllConstraints() {
    var _superview = self.superview
    
    while let superview = _superview {
        for constraint in superview.constraints {
            
            if let first = constraint.firstItem as? UIView, first == self {
                superview.removeConstraint(constraint)
            }
            
            if let second = constraint.secondItem as? UIView, second == self {
                superview.removeConstraint(constraint)
            }
        }
        
        _superview = superview.superview
    }
    
    self.removeConstraints(self.constraints)
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    }
}
```

to use it

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    self?.buttonView.removeAllConstraints()
   // then you can add your constraint as you like 
}
```

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418884/remove-all-constraints-affecting-a-uiview)

Comment: this is not working, button is still at the same position

Answer (score 0):

Removing/add constraints doesn't cause them to be (re)applied.

Call `.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` on your view.  The system will then call `updateConstraints` as part of its next layout pass.  For complex constraint scenarios you may need your own implementation of `updateConstraints`, but for most cases, and definitely yours, this won't be needed (and should generally be avoided unless there is a specific reason to use it - see the docs)

Comment: i tried calling this after new constraints but its not working